# Keyboard hotkeys gone after installing Windows 8

Tags: windows-8

I have an ASUS Republic of Gamers G74SX.  I installed Windows 8 but the hotkeys seem to be missing.  For example, fn + F12 is supposed to increase the volume.  Is there any way to get the hotkeys back?

Comment: I have the same laptop. Dd you upgrade or do a clean install? You will need to download the ASUS drivers for the keyboard (and probably other things too) from their site to get that to work again.

Comment: I did a clean install.  I'l check out the drivers.  Thanks.

Comment: Which driver is it?  I can't find any that look like they are keyboard related: http://rog.asus.com/notebook/17-inch/g74sx/

Comment: Did your laptop not come with a driver CD?

Comment: No it didn't...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look on [this page](http://support.asus.com/download.aspx?SLanguage=en&p=3&s=336&m=G74Sx&os=30) under Utilities at `ATKACPI driver and hotkey-related utilities`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks a lot.  I'll check it out when I get home!  Does it matter if I download Global (DLM), Global, or P2P?

Comment: I'd use Global, DLM requires additional software and I believe P2P would need a torrenting program.

Comment: I installed it but the function keys still aren't working.  Maybe the drivers just aren't compatible.

Comment: I take it back.  The function keys are working.  I just don't get the graphics when using them (which is no big deal).  Thanks!

Comment: This also worked on an Asus U43F

Answer (score 1):

I have an *Asus G72**GX / Win8 x64. **You will find all of the ATK Package versions here:**
ATK Package not related to the Laptop model. I am using the latest now :)

http://support.asus.com/Download.aspx?SLanguage=en&m=ATK_package&os=30

If you can't open the setup.exe file after unpack use:

1. "**Global (DLM)**"    ... wait for downloading ...
2. when it says "**Download Complete!**" choose
3. "**Open** ATKPackage_Win7_64_Z100023.zip"